# Alternative to Triggers on WP8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I've read that `Triggers` are not supported in XAML for WP8. What's the alternative approach? I wanted to use a trigger to change the background image of a button when tapped.

Comment: this article suggests using Visual State and provides an example (and links to other examples): http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/77604041-b991-4f1e-9adb-78c701ac4d9a/ maybe it will help?

Answer (score 0):

You could, potentially just attach an event handler for the "Tap" event for the image.  Without code examples, I'm not too sure how much I can help; however, I've pasted some code below:

**XAML**

```
                <Image Source="/Assets/awesomeImg.png" Tap="AwesomeImg_Tap"/>
```

**Code Behind (C#)**

```
private void AwesomeImg_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
      YourImageName.ImageSource = //code here to URI of image
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, it is a bit different as you are changing the image (view) programmatically.  I would suggest tying the event handler (callback/trigger) to a method in your ViewModel which would take care of following the recommendations.  Keep in mind, that the MVVM are recommendations, not requirements.  For your special case, you might have to break the rules, as WP does not support this natively for you.  This is all just my opinion, though.

Comment: @James Jeffery, if you believe my answer has resolved your question, please consider giving an up-vote or mark my answer for others to know.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.
Windows phone triggers [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh134799(v=expression.40).aspx)

Here I binded the image data trigger with my Boolean property , when the Boolean property is changed it will trigger and the setter will fire. Make sure you properties are implemented with [INofityPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
 xmlns:ec="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions" x:Class="XXX_XXXX"
<Image Source="/Assets/Images/Tick.png"
                   Stretch="None"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <ec:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsTapped}" Value="True">
                        <ec:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Source">
                            <ec:ChangePropertyAction.Value>

                                <BitmapImage UriSource="/Assets/Images/Close.png"/>
                            </ec:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                        </ec:ChangePropertyAction>
                    </ec:DataTrigger>
                </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Image>
```