# LongListSelector set image visibility on selection change

Tags: c#, events, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, longlistselector

I have a `LongListSelector` with some `textblocks`and images inside.

> How can I set the Image's visibility programmatically?

I have them set to `collapsed` and I want to enable them on `selection_changed` event of the `LongListSelector`.

**XAML:**

```
<phone:LongListSelector Name="LongListSel" Margin="0,-38,-22,2" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionChanged="LongListSelector_SelectionChanged">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="12,2,0,4" Height="110" Width="432">
                            <StackPanel Width="311" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineTwo}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,-2,10,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Name="playImage" Height="50" Width="50" Margin="0,0,10,0">
                                <Image Source="Assets/Tiles/Iconsmind-Outline-Play-Music.ico" Visibility="{Binding ImageVis}" Width="50" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Tap="Image_Tap_1"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Name="downloadImage" Height="50" Width="50" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                <Image Source="Assets/Tiles/Download.ico" Visibility="{Binding ImageVis}" Width="50" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Tap="Image_Tap_1"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>
```

**selection changed event:**

```
private void LongListSelector_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ItemViewModel item = new ItemViewModel();
            item.ImageVis = Visibility.Visible;
            //it can't be called the way you are doing it of course and it still doesn't work
        }
```

**ViewModel**

```
        private Visibility _imageVis;
        public Visibility ImageVis
        {
            get { return _imageVis; }
            set
            {
                _imageVis = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ImageVis");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Make your item source as Observable collection. And add an extra Visibility property on your Model class with INotifyPropertyChanged implemented. On selecting an item, change the selected item visibility property. It will reflect on the view.

Comment: If you mean something like the example below it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Create a property of type Visibility an bind it to your image visibility.

ViewModel:

```
    private Visibility _DownloadImage;
    public Visibility DownloadImage
    {
        get { return _DownloadImage; }
        set
        {
            if (_DownloadImage != value)
            {
                _DownloadImage = DownloadImage;
                OnPropertyChanged("DownloadImage");
            }
        }
    }
```

xaml

```
<Image Source="Assets/Tiles/Download.ico" Visibility="{Binding DownloadImage}" ... />
```

xaml.cs (I would prefer to bind the command also to the ViewModel, to keep the MVVM pattern)

```
private void LongListSelector_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DownloadImage = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

Comment: You could use `Data Trigger` see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/29410912/1876572

Comment: That didn't work. I was doing exactly the same thing to be honest before posting here. I updated the code

Comment: I am trying to changes the images visibility when clicking on the TextBlocks btw...